# Loading config before starting to construct/load rootPage

Tags: ionic2

Im building a ionic 2 rc0 app. My rootPage depends on some configuration I have to load before I start my App. I'm using a provider called **Config** all over over the application. How can I delay/wait until configs loaded before constructing my **Home** page component. I need the configs in the constructor of Home. Is there sth. like a preloading module from ionic for situation like that ?

Is that even the best location for tasks like that ?

My Config module uses

`http.get(../assets/config/config.json)
 .toPromise()
 .then(res => this.data = res);`

to load the json file locally into data object of of my Config provider. And my code in **app.component.ts** fires a the function config.loadDefault() to load these default settings from the **config.json** file for the application .....

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';

import { Home } from '../pages/home/home';
import { Config } from '../providers/config/config';

@Component({
  template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
})
export class LoddenApp {

  public rootPage = Home;

  constructor(
    public platform : Platform,
    public config   : Config
  ){
    // loading config
    config.loadDefault()
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return config.loadSettingsFromDB();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("error occured while loading config:");
        console.log(err);
      });


    platform.ready().then(() => {
    ...
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: but how does this prevent loading rootPage before loading the configs ? It's just a method to show a loading spinner on the screen ... for the approach of using LoadingController before the comment was deleted :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By not defining the rootPage until i got back my promise response, I can hold back the constructor of my Home page from firing.

```
...
export class LoddenApp {
  public rootPage : any; // hold back
  constructor(
...
```

Then inside the **then()** block, i can set the rootPage of my app.

```
this.rootPage = Home; // Home is the Homepage component
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution to me.  
I have done something more : loadSettingsFromDB publish an Event when data is really loaded (has DB operations are async operations).
I subscribe to this event to set the rootPage when everything is done

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks @sami_analyst for sharing!

Comment: This is a neat solution

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is the best way to do. But one option is to hide the splash screen after your data gets loaded.

```
import {Splashscreen} from 'ionic-native';

constructor(
    public platform : Platform,
    public config   : Config
  ){

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // loading config
      config.loadDefault()
       .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return config.loadSettingsFromDB();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("error occured while loading config:");
        console.log(err);
      });
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have Not used a splashscreen in my Applications (for now). Does my constructor of the rootPage (Home) Waits until the splashscreen is hidden ? Bay using a splashscreen i just kind if using a Page before using my actual Home Page right ?

Comment: @sami_analyst, though you have not used splash screen, ionic will include its default splash screen and the purpose of showing it is to make user wait till the app gets loaded. But make sure that it is not taking too much of time.

Comment: Did you mean to put Splashscreen.hide() inside the then block of my resloved promise ? But still, this doesn't work either, because the Home page does not wait for the Splashscreen to hide, before it fires the constructor

Comment: yes use it inside the then block. It will work. Your homescreen constructor will run even on splashscreen visibility. Make sure you use  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/> in your config.xml

Comment: But that is exactly what i dont want, I want to load the constructor of my Home Page, after i loaded the configs... Iwant to Start to load the configs with config.loadDefault() while im loadong the configs the splashscreen can be visible until at least the configs are ready, then i want the constructor of my Home Page to fire, because it depends on the configs